# What does 科 in 本科教育 or 本科学历 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word

This question is triggered after reading the post "***What does 本 in 本科教育 or 本科学历 mean?***" In which, the word 本 was well explained, how about 科?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

科 = 学科 (course; subject; branch of learning; field of study)

e.g. 医科，理科，工科，文科 (Medicine, Science, Engineering, Literature)

I study Medicine at the university = 我在大学修读医科(医学)

Comment: Considering the university offers a collection of subjects in different branches, so 本科 means initial/basic subjects?

Comment: @tianz So 本科 means 'four years study of a collection of subjects' and 专科 means 'three years study of a specific subject'? This means 本 in 本科 refers to  'general/ full' and 专 in 专科 refers to 'specific'

Comment: May I ask who is @tianz?

Comment: he deleted his comment

Comment: I see. I think it reflects the **type of study** - 本科, the same as the undergraduate degree that requires finishing certain studies within a certain time frame.  专科, with the time frame shortened, is focused on a certain field with studies narrowly tailored (concentrated) to that field. If the above stand correct, can we say 科 is "field of study", or just "study"?

Comment: I accept it, although I think 傳統教程 and 專業教程 are more close to what type of study that 本科 and 专科 offer. But I doubt 科 can be extended to mean 教程.

Answer (score 2):

本科：基本科目

基本basic
科目 field of study